# How to run Gitlab CI/CD pipeline with no jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a mono repo and I'm trying to kick off child pipelines only if they have changes in them.

In the parent `.gitlab-ci.yml` I have

```yaml
childTrigger:
  trigger:
    include: childdir/.gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend

someOtherJob:
   stage: deploy
   script:
     - "echo other job"
   when: manual
   only:
     - somebranch
   needs: []
```

In the child `.gitlab-ci.yml` I have:

```yaml
myChildJob:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Child job"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "parent_pipeline"
      changes: 
        - somefile.txt
```

This works fine and all when I've made a change to `somefile.txt`, but if I'm not working on `somebranch` nor make a change to `somefile.txt`, Gitlab will error out with something along the lines of "`(downstream pipeline can not be created, Pipeline will not run for the selected trigger.  The rules configuration prevented any jobs from being added to the pipeline)`"

I've tried every combination I can think of to put the rules in the parent and child `.gitlab-ci.yml` files and nothing seems to work.  The best that I could do is create a

```yaml
dummy:
  when: always
  script:
    - echo "Blah Blah Blah"
```

in the child `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.  When I do this, it will run a job in the `test` stage. It's super annoying, but at least it creates a job so that Gitlab doesn't complain.

The question is, how can I can set up a parent/child pipeline in a mono repo so that it only fires off the pipeline if the file has changed in the child dir.